# ViewPager with indicator without Android's support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator, viewpage

Right now I'm using the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) for swipe-able fragments with an indicator in my program and it's working like a charm. But since Google is pushing more and more into the direction of Fragments without using the [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) and e.g. PreferenceFragments aren't available in the support library, I'm wondering if there is something similar to the ViewPagerIndicator that's using the standard Android library.

Answer (score 7):

> Google is pushing more and more into the direction of Fragments without using the Android support library

And your proof of this is... what, exactly?

> e.g. PreferenceFragments aren't available in the support library

It is not possible to backport `PreferenceFragment` very easily, as there are many other requirements to make that useful (e.g., backporting the new `PreferenceActvity`). I have personally looked into backporting the preference fragment system and concluded that it would be significantly more pain than it is worth to me.

> I'm wondering if there is something similar to the ViewPageIndicator that's using the standard Android library

By definition, that is impossible, as `ViewPager` is in the Android Support package, which means any indicator for `ViewPager` must use the Android Support package.

However, there is nothing about `ViewPager` that requires you to use fragments. You are welcome to create your own `PagerAdapter` implementation that does not use any fragments, or uses native API Level 11 fragments, if you so choose.

Comment: I meant _similar_ to ViewPageAdapter. The point is exactly that I don't want implement it myself. I just don't have the time for this.

Comment: @user1278769: There is nothing in Android named `ViewPageAdapter`, so I do not know what you are referring to.

Comment: Please have a look at the link I provided for that reason.

Comment: @user1278769: There is nothing at either link named `ViewPageAdapter`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant ViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: @user1278769: You cannot have anything *similar* to `ViewPagerIndicator` that avoids the Android Support package, because `ViewPager` is in the Android Support package, as I noted in my answer.

Comment: Yes I understand this. Maybe I should rewrite my question then. I'm looking for a library that offers swiping of fragments together with some kind of indicator without using the support library - similar than ViewPagerIndicator offers it for views with the support library.

Comment: @CommonsWare - why is `ViewPager` found **only** in the support Library and not part of the regular API?

Comment: @kilaka: I have not heard an official rationale.